# Why can't I pass arrow functions in the angular component properties

Tags: angular

other component template:

```
<app-search-bar [onSearch]="content => onSearch(content)"></app-search-bar>
```

**Error:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 10 in [content => onSearch(content)]**

app-search-bar.component.ts:

```
...
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  searchText = '';
  @Input() onSearch: (content: string) => void;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

I am a newbie to angular, I don’t know the reason, this is not correct, so that the IDE cannot know what attributes the component transmits. Compared with the programming model of reactjs, this is very unfriendly

Comment: The component "app-search-bar" should fire an event in the main controller to find data? can you share with us the contract of your component and what should be its behaviour?

Comment: @mthkhaled: The search bar completes the search results and returns to the parent component, and the parent component processes the updated data to the list component

Comment: So, you mean that in the html of the parent component, there is a search bar (using app-search-bar) which should fire an event in the parent container to get filtered search results? which will be displayed below it for example in a table? if this is the contract, so what is the event to fire the "onSearch", it will be developed in the component "app-search-bar" ?

Comment: @mthkhaled: Yes, I want to understand the communication structure of angular components first, and then learn about store state management

Answer (score 1):

The template parser allows for basic JavaScript syntax - which can still be used to build up complex statements, but it's advisable to keep it basic

If you need to reference more complex syntax like an arrow function, just assign it to a property on the component and reference that property in the template instead

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0):

The communication between components in angular can be done by several ways:

- [Two way data binding/ Input & Output events/ via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction)...
- Client side state (using [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/))

Let's keep our component so simple, we assume that your application is not subject of state to use [NGRX](https://ngrx.io/) tool (which is recommended for big and complex angular application).

First, your component "app-search-bar" should display for example an input text with a button, the click on the button will fire an event in the parent component in order to get filtered search results to display in the page:

```
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  searchText = '';
  @Output() onSearch = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  constructor() { }
  ...

  fireSearch() {
   this.onSearch.emit(this.searchText);
  }

}
```

And the html of the component "app-search-bar" looks like this:

```
<input type="text" [value]="searchText">
<button (click)="fireSearch()">Search</button>
```

Finally, in the parent container you have to check the event of "onSearch" with the provided content to filter the data and display them anyway in the page:

```
    <app-search-bar (onSearch)="onSearch($event)"></app-search-bar>
    <table>
     <thead>
       <tr> 
        <th>First column</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="data">
       <tr *ngFor="item in data">
        <td>{{ item.columnValue }}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And in the typescript class of the parent component, you have to implement the event like this:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  data;
  ....

  onSearch(content: string) {
   // do some staff here to filter the data and assign it to the property "data"
   this.data = ....;
  }

}
```

This is a very basic example which help you understanding more about the communication of a component with its container via Output events.

[I recommend you to follow the official documentation of Angular which will guide you to develop a sample app and help you understand all the great features of Angular framework.](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

Comment: Thank you for your extra help. I will learn more about component communication.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept this answer if my solution works for you @ProJin